# Why doesn't Windows 7 allow write mode on networked drives?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, permissions, network-shares, usb-flash-drive

Windows 7 Home Premium does not allow write mode on USB networked drives, why is this? Is anyone else having this issue also?

I can network drives in read mode but read/write mode isn't working! Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue with user rights, I right clicked on the drives and gave myself and all users that needed rights, "read & write" access, the default was only read access.

Answer (score 2):

[This thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproinstall/thread/20e8e21f-c555-4d09-bc46-26cf9926d105) is dealing with backups, and it does seem to be a limitation of Home Premium that it can't write to networked drives (not just USB ones) *for this particular case*

Comment: Wait... is the limitation with Home Premium that you can't write to a networked drive or that you can't use the included Microsoft backup software to write to a networked drive? I.e. can you use 3rd party backup software or xcopy to write to a networked drive? If the limitation is only with MS's included system backup/restore feature, that's not as bad a loss.

Comment: @bill, unfortunately the thread comments weren't 100% clear & I haven't had the time to investigate further. I found the link and thought the OP might find it useful. The OP didn't say what s/w was failing to write to the networked drive either.

Comment: Okay. It looks like you can write to network drives in Windows 7 Home Premium; the restriction comes in with the integrated Windows Backup software. You can use other backup solutions (or standard file copy operations) to backup files to a network.